# How can I select ntp the time source for a system?

Tags: timeout, ntp, time, ntpd

I have two Windows 2008 servers running Meinburg NTP. When I run ntpq.exe -p from one, I see that there are sources specified as current, selected, or discarded (via a +, -, or *). On another system, it shows the same sources; but there are no marks in front of the names. When I try querying these boxes from a linux host (using ntpdc), only the system that shows if a source is selected, discarded, etc. works; the other system times out.

What do I need to do to get these time sources configured correctly?

Comment: You can't use the built-in NTP client Windows has?  That's easy to configurate.

Comment: Is it possible to configure meinburg ntp with the default ntp client? I would prefer a way to do this via cmd or a script also; there are a lot of systems with this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've never heard of this ntp software, so I don't know.  I was honestly suggesting using the built-in Windows NTP client and server instead of this one.

Comment: Out of curiousity, why are you not using the built-in Windows NTP client?  It has made the need for third party NTP software pretty much irrelevant.